# How do I use a Webcam feed as an A-Frame texture?

Tags: webrtc, aframe

I'd like to attach a webcam stream as a texture to an entity within an [aframe](https://aframe.io/), is this possible and how would I do that?

An example of the effect I'm going for include:

- Projecting my webcam feed onto a TV within the vr
- "Face timing" someone within VR
- Seeing yourself within the VR for debugging purposes

Answer (score 7):

https://media.giphy.com/media/cJjZg8kXSUopNzZP4V/giphy.gif

### Adding the Asset

The first step is to add the video as an asset:

```
<a-assets>
  <video id="webcam" playsinline></video>
</a-assets>
```

Note the playsinline directive which prevents the page from entering full screen mode, particularly on mobile devices. It’s just a little detail I like to add, because while our app will be run fullscreen anyways I want the app to decide that and not some random video element!

### Create the Stream

Next we create the stream with:

```
<!-- Start the webcam stream and attach it to the video element -->
<script>
  // You can also set which camera to use (front/back/etc)
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: false, video: true})
  .then(stream => {
    let $video = document.querySelector('video')
    $video.srcObject = stream
    $video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
      $video.play()
    }
  })
</script>
```

### Apply the Texture

Finally, we apply the stream as a material onto any entity with: `material="src: #webcam"`

### Working Demo

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>

<!-- Create an empty video tag to hold our webcam stream -->
<a-assets>
  <video id="webcam" playsinline></video>
</a-assets>

<!-- Creates -->
<a-scene background="color: #ECECEC">
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" shadow material="src: #webcam"></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E" shadow></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D" shadow></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" shadow></a-plane>
</a-scene>

<!-- Start the webcam stream and attach it to the video element -->
<script>
  // You can also set which camera to use (front/back/etc)
  // @SEE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: false, video: true})
  .then(stream => {
    let $video = document.querySelector('video')
    $video.srcObject = stream
    $video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
      $video.play()
    }
  })
</script>
```

If the Code Runner doesn't work, you can also play with it here: https://glitch.com/~webcam-as-aframe-texture

Comment: This is really cool. If we run it in mobile browser, can it use front and back camera?

Comment: This is a great answer, but note that adding the code in the script tag, at least as of version 1.0.4, breaks it and is considered non-semantic in aframe. It doesn't work for me if I do it that way, but if I run the code in the console after page load, all is good. That's exactly the type of error one should expect when running script tags manually with aframe--you need to give aframe control over execution time.